# Small submodules of direct sum of two modules

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Recall that a submodule $N$ of a module $M$ is called small if $N+K=M$ implies that $K=M$ for any submodule $K$ of $M$.

Recall that for any module $M$ over a ring $R$, $ann(M)=\{r\in R|rM=0\}$.

The following result has been used in a reasearch paper (title: small compressible and small retractable modules)

**Result:** Let $M=M_1\oplus M_2$ be a module over a ring $R$ with identity $1$ such that $ann(M_1)+ann(M_2)=R$. If $N$ is a small submodule of $M$, then there exists small submodules $K_1$ in $M_1$ and $K_2$ in $M_2$ such that $N=K_1\oplus K_2$.

I have no idea how to prove this result. Suggest any idea if possible. It will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $r\in \operatorname{ann}(M_1)$ and $s\in\operatorname{ann}(M_2)$ such that $r+s=1$, and let $K_1=sN$ and $K_2=rN$.  Since $r+s=1$, $K_1+K_2=N$, and $K_1\subseteq M_1$ since $s$ annihilates $M_2$ and $K_2\subseteq M_2$ since $r$ annihilates $M_1$.

It remains to show that $K_i$ is small in $M_i$; by symmetry it suffices to show this for $i=1$.  Suppose $K\subseteq M_1$ and $M_1=K+K_1$.  Then $M=K+K_1+M_2$.  Since $K_1\subseteq N$ and $N$ is small in $M$, this implies $K+M_2=M$.  Since $K\subseteq M_1$ and $M$ is the direct sum of $M_1$ and $M_2$, this implies $K$ is all of $M_1$.

Comment: I have a small doubt. In the paper, authors also used the fact that if $N$ is nonzero, then $K_1$ and $K_2$ both must be nonzero. But we have examples like $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_4$ in which this is not true. Is it true?

Answer (score 3):

By assumption, for some $a_i\in \mathrm{ann}(M_i)$ we have $a_1+a_2=1$, so $N=a_1N+a_2N$. Let $K_1=a_2N,\ K_2=a_1N$. It is easy to see that $K_i\subset M_i$ and $K_1\oplus K_2=N$.
Moreover, if $a_2N+L=M_1$, then $$(a_2N\oplus a_1N)+(L\oplus M_2)\supset M_1\oplus M_2=M$$
holds and so by assumption
$$L\oplus M_2= M_1\oplus M_2, L=M_1.$$
Hence, $K_1$ is small. For $K_2$ the argument is the same.

Comment: I'm sorry that I sent almost the same answer. Should I erase?